# Any possibility to crawl open web browser data using aperture

Tags: java, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I known about crawl website using Aperture. if i open http://demo.crawljax.com/ in mozila web browser. how can crawl open browser content using Aperture.

Steps:
1. Open http://demo.crawljax.com/ on your mozila firefox.
2. Executed java program to crawl open mozila firefox tab.

Comment: Its not possible to get content from firefox browser. You can use any other testing tool to do that. For example, [Crawljax](http://crawljax.com/)

Comment: yes kumar. but we couldn't get content.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936719/how-to-get-crawl-content-in-crawljax/27937158#27937158

Comment: What you need actually? Why you want to crawl from the browser? A normal crawler will work fine like aperture.

Comment: A lot of tools are available for crawling. All tools are crawl only static website(Plain HTML). crawljax Tools can able to move dynamic website link.. If this question is possible, we have implement Aperture coding in crawljax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its imposable to crawl the open Webbrowser data using Aperture. A Crawljax is Testing tools and it will open new Web browser and Testing data.. i have Ensuring Crawling Dynamic Website Data Using Crawljax.

Ref URL : http://demo.crawljax.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to crawl the JavaScript/Ajax page. You actually need a crawler like googlebot. See [this](http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/googlebot-crawling-javascript-site-ready/03062014/) googlebot can crawl the javascript page. You can do it using some other drivers/crawlers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365154/web-crawling-ajax-javascript-enabled-pages-using-java) similar question found. You can try out the best answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27268640/3496666)